# Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] Unknown option: base.stage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I upgraded my react/webpack app using `ncu` and it updated babelify to 7.2.0 (and hence babel to 6.0.0). Now I am getting the following error:

`ERROR in ./app/main.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /home/ben/simple-webpack-react-starter/app/main.js: Unknown option: base.stage`

Ive looked through a bunch of stack overflow posts with the same or similar errors and have done everything suggested. I'm pretty stuck! Please help. Here are the relevant files i think:

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "MODA",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Online Annotations",
  "main": "server/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
    "dev-web": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack-dev.config.js --hot --progress --colors --content-base build",
    "dev": "nodemon server/index.js --watch server & webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack-dev.config.js --hot --progress --colors --content-base build",
    "build": "rm build/*; webpack --config ./webpack-prod.config.js --progress --colors",
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "test": "karma start",
    "testing": "karma start --single-run=false"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.5.0",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "ejs": "*",
    "aws-sdk": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.0.0",
    "npm": "2.14.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.0.15",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "expect": "^1.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "json-fs": "^1.1.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.19",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-cli": "0.1.2",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.5.1",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.3.7",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-draggable": "^1.1.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.7",
    "react-resizable-box": "^0.1.7",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sinon": "^1.15.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.9.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

And the relevant part of my webpack-common.config

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules | bower_components)/,
    loader: "babel",
    query: {
        presets:['es2015','stage-0', "react"]
    },
},
```

Comment: Has your project a `.babelrc` file on the root?

Comment: No, i thought webpack-common.config covered that? 
I ended up giving up downgrading babel. All is working now. Thanks though!

Comment: Nope, the babel-loader cover both behaviours :-/

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I fixed it by eliminating the query in the config file and instead making a .babelrc file at project root like so:

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [
    {
      "plugins": [
        "./build/babelRelayPlugin"
      ]
    },
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
  ]
}
```